# Somar valores de uma coluna em duas tabelas no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Sou iniciante em programação e gostaria de saber como faço para somar valores de 1 coluna em 2 tabelas, ambas com os mesmos dados. Apenas muda o nome da tabela...

Por exemplo:

Tabela `teste1`:

```
nome | pontos |
Joao |   10   |
```

Tabela `teste2`:

```
nome | pontos |
Joao | 10     |
```

Quero que retorne assim:

```
Nome | Total
Joao |  20
```

Tentei usar `JOIN`, `UNION`, `UNION ALL` e não consigo...

Eu usei:

```
SELECT nome AS nome, pontos AS total from teste1 where nome = 'Joao'
UNION ALL
SELECT nome AS nome, pontos AS total from teste2 where nome = 'Joao'
```

Ao qual o meu retorno é:

```
nome  |  total
Joao  |   10
Joao  |   10
```

Como retornar o total dessa *query*: `10 + 10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem? Apesar de já utilizar a comunidade há muitos anos, eu também sou usuária nova, mas vou tentar contribuir...

Existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso, mas uma forma "simples" é somar as duas colunas int e utilizar um INNER JOIN para agrupar elas pelo campo NOME.

```
SELECT teste1.pontos+teste2.pontos AS total FROM teste1 INNER JOIN teste2 ON(teste1.nome = teste2.nome) WHERE teste1.nome="joao"
```

Quando utilizamos INNER JOIN garantimos que nas duas tabelas existam valores para aqueles campos e que eles sejam iguais... te aconselho uma leitura mais aprofundada, mas existem LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, outras abordagens que podem ser interessantes para você também.

Obrigada.

ps: não testei o código, fiz com base o seu select.

Comment: Me ajudou muito, muito obrigado!!!